# Is there an explanation for the contradiction between "Voyager" and "The Undiscovered Country"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, the-undiscovered-country

In the *Star Trek: Voyager* episode "Flashback", Dimitri Valtane is killed. In *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country*, he is shown to still be alive at the end of the film on board the Excelsior.  Is there an in-universe explanation for this contradiction to canon?

Comment: Tuvok was infected with a "memory virus". Possibly he just mis-remembered, since chunks of this episode seem to be told from his personal perspective.